# "margin: 0 auto" doesn't work when width is defined

Tags: html, css

I was creating a search tool for my website, and i wanted it to be in center, So i created main div container that would hold every search tool element, which had `margin: 0 auto` and it worked. **But inside it another element which had `margin: 0 auto;` would not be centered.**

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbox">
        <div class="mover">
           <input type="text" name="searchfield" class="search" placeholder="Search Item">
```

CSS:

```
.searchbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0%;
  top: 55px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
}
.mover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
}
.search {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 35px;
  top: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.search[type=text] {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

**Please note that i do not want `width: 100%` for search element, as you see in code, i have `min-width: 600px` defined, which is for other elements in mover which is not relevant in this case.**

Please check out, [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z656o7qv/)

What could the problem be? I have defined width on both elements, but margin auto still doesn't work, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<input>` is an inline-level element, the `margin: auto` tricks only works for block level elements.

You can do:

```
.search {
  ...
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block; /*add this line*/
}
```

Or, if you prefer leave it as inline you can do:

```
.mover {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, now input element is horizontally centered, but `top` or `margin-top` do not work at all, is there a way to fix it without messing up?

Comment: The modern way of centering is to use flexbox, see this https://jsfiddle.net/sy258f2w/

Comment: Sorry i asked pointless question, `position: relative;` fixed the problem, but yeah i'm definetely gonna try out flexbox.